# Chrome extension content_scripts matching for any tld

Tags: json, google-chrome-extension

Trying to match any tld for google. IE: google.ca, google.com etc... However it only allows for the entire host to be a wildcard. Not part of the host.

This is all within "content_scripts": [] in the extentions manifest.json file.

So this works:

```
"matches" : [ "*://*.google.com/*", "*://*.google.ca/*" ],
```

But this does not:

```
"matches" : [ "*://*.google.*/*" ],
```

Nor does this:

```
"matches" : [ "*://*.google*/*" ],
```

Just throws an error on activation. I really don't want to have to fill in all the Google TLDs as separate elements. Anyone have any thoughts on this one?

Comment: Ah thats it. Thanks wOxxOm

Comment: I guess this is different than http://stackoverflow.com/q/32396890/2336725, but I find it interesting these questions were posted only four hours apart.